# Creating user API using RESTful module in Drupal 7

Tags: php, rest, drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to figure out how to create a RESTful API to CRUD the users of a Drupal 7 instance.  It would be preferred to use the following module because other parts of the site uses it:
https://github.com/RESTful-Drupal/restful
If there's a better restful module out there I would be willing to give it a shot.

The documentation shows a little bit of how to use it with articles.  What do I need to change to users?  Is there a tutorial out there I can follow?

Comment: This piece of documentation https://github.com/RESTful-Drupal/restful/wiki/Saving-an-entity-back-to-Drupal implies that one can send a payload to any endpoint. The problem with what you're trying to achieve is that in order to do this your user will need to be logged in.

Answer (score 1):

You will get more joy and it will be more secure if you make your own end point in a module, just for registering users.

First, in your module's .module file, make use of the hook_menu function

```
/*
 * hook_menu
 */
function yourmodule_menu() {
    $items['yourmodule/user/register'] = array(
        'page callback' => 'yourmodule_user_register',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    );
    return $items;
}
```

Then create the callback function:

```
/*
 * hook_menu page callback
 */
function yourmodule_user_register() {

    // if you want to send the payload using content type 'application/json'
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    // otherwise use $_POST

    // if you have autoloader set up
    $register = new YourmoduleUserRegister($obj);
    // otherwise add in your logic here to validate and save user data

}
```

Once you have validated your user data, using the [drupal API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/7) methods user_load_by_mail() and user_load_by_name(), use user_save() to register the user. You can whitelist origin URLs and do other security things here too.

Comment: Thanks for your time responding to this. However, one small but important point: I think you should never assume one-off code you write for yourself will be more secure. It will have a degree of security-by-obscurity to it, but unless you're extraordinarily well versed in security exploits, the safest way is to leverage a public code base that's had many eyes pass over it.